# How do we nominate someone else for moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I don't have 300 points, so I can't nominate myself. But that is a good thing, because I have no interest in being a moderator. However, I'm a heavy lurker on gaming.stackexchange, and I'd like to nominate some others that appear to be good community members. Is this possible?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75382/how-can-you-nominate-someone-other-than-yourself-for-being-a-moderator

Comment: As Fabian said, Nominating others is not possible. If you want to call them out and encourage them to nominate, try pinging them [in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge)

Comment: Thanks. I searched for the question prior to posting, wondering why the linked question didn't come up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nominating others is intentionally not possible.

Comment: To expand on this: The best way to "nominate" someone else is for you to convince them that they should nominate themselves.

Comment: ... or hack their accounts in order to nominate them

Answer (score 5):

When we did allow outside nominations, it caused a lot of problems:

- users often did not *know* they were nominated by someone else
- users sometimes *did not want* to be nominated at all
- it implies a lot of coordination, more than there actually is, between users

There is, I think, an important difference between nominating yourself and accepting someone else's nomination. While in *theory* this could work and feels very democratic, in practice it typically does not, and has a small but significant chance of causing confusion and possible hard feelings.

Best to let users nominate themselves so there is no chance of confusion or misunderstanding. I also think people who self-nominate are the most motivated to participate, anyway.